# Find tweets by app

Tags: twitter, search, twitter-api

I need to find all tweets made by a defined app.

I discovered the "source" search operator that allows to do that.

For example, here is the URL of the search to find all tweets made with Tweetbot for iOS:
https://twitter.com/#!/search/source%3ATweetbot_for_iOS

The problem is I need to get the result as JSON or XML. 
Here is what is indicated on the [Twitter search API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search)

> 1. Run your search on twitter.com/search.
> 2. Copy the URL. For example:
>      https://twitter.com/#!/search/%40twitterapi
> 3. Replace
>      https://twitter.com/#!/search/ with
>      http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=. For example:
>      http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%40twitterapi

It gives us http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=source%3ATweetbot_for_iOS
which returns

> error: "Invalid query"

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is found on the [Twitter search API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search)

> > **source**
> >
> > - can only be combined with a keyword parameter. If you do not include a keyword you will receive an HTTP 403 error with the message: {"error":"You must enter a query."}.
> > - supports multi-word sources by using _ instead of spaces. For example, the source "Tweet Button" should be entered as source: tweet_button

Therefor you must include a keyword. You can't get all the tweets from a source, you can only get all the tweets from the source which including a keyword, for example FBI:

> > http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=fbi&source%3ATweetbot_for_iOS

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That explains why I get the error message.
However I would really appreciate finding another way to achieve that search.

Answer (score 1):

*Why* you get the error message, `@mhoran_psprep` explained that. Now if you still want to achieve something like that, the closest thing is to choose a keyword, that is likely to appear in every other tweet and search with that + the source. There is no *word* like that, so I chose a letter. `:P`

I searched with the letter `a` and the source as `tweetdeck`.

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=a%20source:tweetdeck
```

The search works. The character `a` is likely to appear in most tweets. You can choose any other letter too. See if this works for you too. :)

Comment: That's a good idea